# A random sample of $50$ machines obtained that its average life is $\bar{x}=70$ months with a variance of $s^2=49$. Confidence interval for variance.

Tags: variance, confidence-interval

I need help with the part b) of this exercise.

A random sample of $50$ machines obtained that its average life is $\bar{x}=70$ months with a variance of $s^2=49$. Assume that they are normally distributed and based on this:

a) Construct a 90% confidence interval for the population variance.

Degrees of freedom: $n-1=50-1=49$

Critical value:

- Left: $\chi_{0.05,49}^2=33.93031$

> qchisq(0.05,49)

> [1] 33.93031

- Right: $\chi_{0.95,49}^2=66.33865$

> qchisq(0.95,49)

> [1] 66.33865

$$(\frac{(50-1)49}{66.33865},\frac{(50-1)49}{33.93031})$$

$$(36.19308,70.7627)$$

b) What sample size will be needed to do a new investigation if we want 96% confidence and a margin of error of 1.5 months?

Here is where I don't know what to do. In my class notes I can't find the formula for a sample size for a confidence interval for a variance. I just find the formula for sample size for a confidence interval for a mean or for a proportion. I both of those formula I see that the squared critical value is multiplied by the variance and  that product is divided by the squared margin of error. But how I can find the critical value here if for the confindence interval of a population variance there are two different critical values and I need the degrees of freedom to find them and I don't have the sample size, in fact that's what I'm looking for. :-S

I haven't used here the sample mean. So, I was wondering if this is supposed to be a sample size for a confindence interval of a population mean, but the premise doesn't say it.

HELP! PLEASE!

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's think about what the second part of the question is asking for.  You know that for a $100(1-\alpha)\%$ confidence interval for the variance will be $$\left(\frac{(n-1)s^2}{\chi_{1-\alpha/2,n-1}^2}, \frac{(n-1)s^2}{\chi_{\alpha/2,n-1}^2}\right). \tag{1}$$  So the margin of error is half of the length of this interval, i.e., $$ME = \frac{(n-1)s^2}{2} \left( \frac{1}{\chi_{\alpha/2,n-1}^2} - \frac{1}{\chi_{1-\alpha/2,n-1}^2}\right). \tag{2}$$

We are given $ME = 1.5$, $s^2 = 49$, and $\alpha = 0.04$.  Our goal is to find $n$.  One way to do this is through guess-and-check.  What would be a good initial guess?

I searched online but could not find any formulas to address this question, so I turned to some empirical data analysis.  Note that the following is claimed **without** proof, so any other interested readers may wish to cite the relevant literature, or furnish a proof themselves.

First, I claim that for sufficiently large $n$, $$ME \approx \frac{s^2}{\sqrt{n}} \cdot \sqrt{2} \,  z_{1-\alpha/2} \tag{3}$$ where $z_{1-\alpha/2}$ is the $1-\alpha/2$ quantile of the standard normal distribution.  Again, I found this formula through empirical study; if anyone has a proof, I would welcome it.  Using this, we can easily calculate an initial guess for $n$:  we have
$$n \approx \frac{2 s^4 z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{ME^2} \approx 9001.9. \tag{4}$$  Rounding up to the nearest integer $n = 9002$, we substitute this into $(2)$ and get $ME = 1.50074$.  Since this is too large, we calculate additional values in the following table:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
n & ME \\
\hline
 9003 & 1.50066 \\
 9004 & 1.50057 \\
 9005 & 1.50049 \\
 9006 & 1.50041 \\
 9007 & 1.50032 \\
 9008 & 1.50024 \\
 9009 & 1.50016 \\
 9010 & 1.50007 \\
 \color{red}{9011} & \color{red}{1.49999} \\
 9012 & 1.49991 \\
\end{array}$$

The exact value, is $n = 9011$, corresponding to the first value in the table for which $ME \le 1.5$.